# How does imfilter 'replicate' in matlab work for bigger filters?

Tags: matlab

I am reading this:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/imfilter-boundary-padding-options.html

And I am trying to understand how it will work for 5x5, or 7x7 kernels. Let's say in a 5x5 kernel you will have an extra row and column, on the top and right side of the kernel compared to the one in the image in the link. What value will that take ? Just the closest one it can find ? And how about diagonal values (the ones in the corners) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for the [`'replicate'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html#input_argument_d119e70971) option in `imfilter`,

> Input array values outside the bounds of the array are assumed to equal the nearest array border value.

You can actually see the exact array that `imfilter` uses by calling `padarray` with the proper arguments. Say we have a 5x5 array:

```
im = reshape(1:25, 5, 5)
im =
    1    6   11   16   21
    2    7   12   17   22
    3    8   13   18   23
    4    9   14   19   24
    5   10   15   20   25
```

We can pad this array by 2 on each side (the equivalent of using a 5x5 kernel):

```
padarray(im, [2 2], 'replicate')
ans =
    1    1    1    6   11   16   21   21   21
    1    1    1    6   11   16   21   21   21
    1    1    1    6   11   16   21   21   21
    2    2    2    7   12   17   22   22   22
    3    3    3    8   13   18   23   23   23
    4    4    4    9   14   19   24   24   24
    5    5    5   10   15   20   25   25   25
    5    5    5   10   15   20   25   25   25
    5    5    5   10   15   20   25   25   25
```

Spacing out the rows/columns so you can see the original array more easily:

```
1    1       1    6   11   16   21      21   21
1    1       1    6   11   16   21      21   21

1    1       1    6   11   16   21      21   21
2    2       2    7   12   17   22      22   22
3    3       3    8   13   18   23      23   23
4    4       4    9   14   19   24      24   24
5    5       5   10   15   20   25      25   25

5    5       5   10   15   20   25      25   25
5    5       5   10   15   20   25      25   25
```

You can also verify this by creating a kernel with a single `1` value in one of the corners:

```
im = reshape(1:25, 5, 5)
im =
    1    6   11   16   21
    2    7   12   17   22
    3    8   13   18   23
    4    9   14   19   24
    5   10   15   20   25

k = zeros(5); k(1,1) = 1
k =

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0

imfilter(im, k, 'replicate')
ans =
    1    1    1    6   11
    1    1    1    6   11
    1    1    1    6   11
    2    2    2    7   12
    3    3    3    8   13
```

Naturally, this only shows the top-left 5x5 subarray of the 9x9 padded array, but by repeating the process with the `1` in different corners you can see the whole array.

Comment: Great explanatiin. For the OP, just note that `replicate` is a specific option there, you can choose other options as zeros, symmetric or circular, and choose as well if the size of the result will be the same as original or full with the boundaries.

Comment: Yes, for the existing rows/columns, it just duplicates the nearest column/row. For example, `im(:, 1)` is duplicated `floor(k/2)` times to the left, and `im(:, end)` is duplicated `floor(k/2)` times to the right. (Similarly for the top and bottom rows.) The remaining corners simply take the nearest corner value.